# Pushing a .NET artifact built by NuGet to Nexus using Bamboo

Tags: .net, nuget, nexus, bamboo, artifact

I have a .NET project for which there is a Bamboo plan configured. My .NET artifact is built by NuGet and I would like to push this artifact to Nexus using Bamboo. I am relatively new to Bamboo and badly stuck with this issue. Any help or documentation suggesting the solution is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "nuget.exe" command line tool to build an publish this as a nuget package.  You can find information about this here:  https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/nuget-deploying_packages_to_nuget_hosted_repositories.html

Be sure to follow the link at the bottom of that page to find inforamation on how to use the nuget.exe command line.